# Lat/long gets reset after updating

Tags: 7, location

At the moment I'm having some struggles with the location module in Drupal, well I'm not really sure that it's the location module that is causing the problems.

The best I can explain it with a little code. There is a module which connects to a backoffice and gets venues with lat / longitudes.

I do the following:

```
    dpm($node->field_address[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]);
    node_save($node);
    dpm($node->field_address[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]);
```

Before updating the node the values are in the object

```
    array(6) {
      ["street"]=>
      string(16) "Street 1"
      ["city"]=>
      string(7) "Middle earth"
      ["postal_code"]=>
      string(7) "12345"
      ["latitude"]=>
      string(8) "52.000"
      ["longitude"]=>
      string(7) "4.000"
      ["location_settings"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["form"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["fields"]=>
          array(2) {
            ["latitude"]=>
            array(1) {
              ["default"]=>
              string(8) "52.000"
            }
            ["longitude"]=>
            array(1) {
              ["default"]=>
              string(7) "4.000"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

After saving the node the lat / long is reset to int(0). 
The lat / long in the location settings is still in tact.

I've search a long time to debug this, i was thinking maybe there's a hook that resets the value, but I just can't find it. I'm fairly new to Drupal so any help will be appreciated :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

The lat/long came from a different source and when the location module tried updating the lat/long I got NULL/NULL, because I was on the max amount of requests to google.

Solution was to set the 'source' column in the location table to 1, so the module thinks the value is overruled by the user. The lat/long doesn't get updated / reset to null anymore.